VB.NET HTTP Handler to perform authentication and authorization
I maintain a VB.NET (.NET framework 4.6.1) web service that consists of a collection of .ashx files (HTTP Handlers) that serve as web service endpoints.  I'm trying to implement a base class that all services in the /InternalServices directory inherit from to centralize cross-cutting concerns such as authentication and authorization.  My goal is to avoid duplicating authentication/authorization code for each web service endpoint.
Here's what I've tried:

Created the base class to inherit from

    <%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="BaseInternalServicesHandler" %>
    
    Imports System.Web

    Public MustInherit Class BaseInternalServicesHandler : Implements IHttpHandler
    
      Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        ' Perform authentication/authorization in here
      End Sub

      Protected MustOverride Sub HandleRequest(context As HttpContext)

      Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
      End Property
  End Class


Added 2 ChatGPT-suggested configurations to web.xml

.
.
<handlers>
  <add name="BaseInternalServicesHandler" path="InternalServices/*.ashx" verb="*" type="Namespace.BaseInternalServicesHandler, AssemblyName" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
.
.
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="InternalServices/*.ashx" verb="*" type="Namespace.BaseInternalServicesHandler, AssemblyName"/>
</httpHandlers>
.
.


Make web service endpoint inherit the base class and override the HandleRequest() function

<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="MyWebServiceEndpoint" %>

Public Class MyWebServiceEndpoint : Inherits BaseInternalServicesHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub HandleRequest(context As HttpContext)
        ' My web service logic here
    End Sub

Am I going about this in the right way? I must be doing something wrong because I'm getting a build error in my MyWebServiceEndpoint class: Type 'BaseInternalServicesHandler' is not defined.  And I currently have BaseInternalServicesHandler and MyWebServiceEndpoint in the same directory.
